# How can I get a simple curve function from a set of points on a touch trajectory?

Tags: function, curve, vertices

I want to get a curve function from a set of points which made by user touch trajectory on touch screen devices. If a user draws trajectory by finger touch very slowly, points input data would increase tremendously. But I want to get a compact curve function even if lots of points data income.
For example, a trajectory looks like character 'U' is consist of 100 vertices, i want get a simple curve function with 3 or 5 control points.
Can you give me an advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a least square spline fitting to the point data in you trajectory. This will often save a lot of memory and storage. The problem is if you want to do the least square spline fitting in real time (i.e., as your finger is moving along the device's screen), it might not be fast enough to catch up with the finger's movement. So, it is recommended to do the spline fitting only when users lift up the finger.